# A tool to generate diagrams of python3 code

Tags: python, diagram

I am trying to find a tool that analyzes code to auto-generate diagrams of my entire project, (dozen of files, thousand of methods, dozens of classes, etc).

I found https://pynsource.com/ but it only create diagrams of a single file, it doesn't retroactively analyze code and create diagrams of imported files, methods, etc.

So, to clarify: I want a tool that creates a **massive** diagram with all the hundred of classes/methods/files/stuff in my project.

What do you recommend? Does something like that even exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several such tools, one of the most commonly used being the combination of [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) with [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/).

Doxygen will analyse your code to create documentation for code written in any of:

- C++,
- C, Objective-C,
- C#,
- PHP,
- Java,
- *Python*,
- IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors),
- Fortran,
- VHDL, etc

Additionally, you can annotate your source code to structure and improve the documentation. It will optionally produce [dot language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) files and invoke GraphViz to diagram the code relationships.

You do have configure your project to let Doxygen know where to find your installed GraphViz dot tool, *(the `bin` directory of where you installed GraphViz)* as can be done in the Dot page of the Expert view of DoxyWizard.
[image: DozyWazrd Expert-Dot]

Both tools are free, gratis & open source and are available for numerous platforms.

Comment: Highly recommended! In fact, industry standard for many programming languages. You will get class diagrams, including inheritance, plus function call tress, plus much more, including annotated code, where you can click to see class/function/variable declaration & usage. Although you can get much of he latter from PyCharm

Comment: I use PyCharm, freaking great for code completion but I found it a bit too limited to analyze code for diagram connections. Or I'm retard and I don't understand it.

Comment: @Saelyth - I have used the above combination for many years now and it is awesome for multiple languages and highly complex projects - you have to play about with the settings a bit to get exactly what you want - I suspect you will need to use the node count and depth settings on the above page (scrolling down a bit).

Comment: I love DOxygen, and it's excellent for the class/module/etc documentation, but are their any tools which make an effort to create diagrams of the control flow?

Comment: @MikeSadler - That sounds worthy of a question in its own merits. You will have to expand a bit on what you are looking for. Hint there are some tools which, with some effort, can diagram control flows but they don't belong in a comment or in the answer to __this__ question.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveBarnes - I've put up a new question!